# Intermittent "Invalid Key" erros when using JavaScript SDK 2.0 to update records

Tags: rally

My application uses the data model to update tasks, as described in the doc https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/data_models.

It works fine most of the time, but occasionally my users are getting an "Invalid key" error from the Rally service.  I haven't found a way to reproduce the issue.

If I look at the requests that are getting sent to Rally, it seems like the SDK fetches a key one time, when it first does an update, and then does subsequent updates with the one key (which usually works fine).

I have two questions concerning this:

1. Is there a specific circumstance that will cause this error (so that I can reproduce it and deal with it?)
2. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I found a way to reproduce this issue consistently.

1. I bring up my custom tool, and use it to do a save or update operation.
2. Leaving my tool open, I go to another tab and I bring up rally1.dev.com and I delete all my cookies there. Then I re-login on the site.
3. I go back to my tool, which is still open. Now whenever I save, I get the "Invalid key" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security token is supposed to be valid for as long as the HTTP session is valid, and it is the browser that maintains the session via a session cookie. A few days ago I have seen a case where a security token sporadically became invalid (more restrictive than it needs to be) and the application responded with "Not authorized to perform action: Invalid key". In this case the error could not be attributed to a valid session timeout(e.g. caused by inactivity beyond a timeout interval). It was replicated by repeatedly accessing `/slm/webservice/v2.0/security/authorize` 
to see how many times a key can be retrieved. 
There seemed to be no specific pattern. I submitted a defect. I am afraid at this point I don't have a better answer.